# using 'ifelse' in R: variable taking static value

Tags: r

I am trying to create new variable in a dataset based on the value of an indicator. The following is the code for the same:

```
prac_data <- head(iris,10)
COPY_IND='Y' ##declaring the indicator to be 'Y'
prac_data <- prac_data %>% mutate(New_Var=ifelse(COPY_IND=='Y', Sepal.Length, 'N'))
```

I get the following output:

```
    Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species New_Var
1           5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa     5.1
2           4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa     5.1
3           4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa     5.1
4           4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2  setosa     5.1
5           5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2  setosa     5.1
6           5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4  setosa     5.1
7           4.6         3.4          1.4         0.3  setosa     5.1
8           5.0         3.4          1.5         0.2  setosa     5.1
9           4.4         2.9          1.4         0.2  setosa     5.1
10          4.9         3.1          1.5         0.1  setosa     5.1
```

I actually want to copy the variable 'Sepal.Length' in the 'New_Var' for every observation if indicator(COPY_IND) is Yes('Y').

If I do the the following, I get the desired response:

```
if (COPY_IND=='Y')
{
  prac_data$New_Var <- prac_data$Sepal.Length

} else {prac_data$New_Var <- 'N'}
```

I just want to understand why R treats both 'if-else' approaches differently?

Is there another better elegant way to the same?

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: `ifelse` works element by element. `if` works by testing a single element and then does an operation. Read their help pages: `?ifelse` and `?'if'` (noting the necessary quotes since like `for` and `function`, `if` is a reserved word and needs to be quoted to use the `?` function. By giving only a single value to `ifelse`, you got only a single value in return, and it was then handled my R's recycling mechanism.

Comment: @M.D Thanks a lot!! I had started to think that it is not possible using the dplyr option. This works!! Great.

Comment: Yeah, the `if` and `ifelse` difference got me recently too... `ifelse(TRUE, 1:3, 0)` vs `if(TRUE) 1:3 else 0`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, this might be easier to read as an answer.

From `ifelse()` help: "ifelse **returns a value with the same shape as test** which is filled with elements selected from either yes or no depending on whether the element of test is TRUE or FALSE".

Your test is just a single value, so `ifelse()` returns a single value, either `Sepal.Length[1]` or `N`, which is then duplicated across the whole column.

You need `rowwise()` on your way: `prac_data <- prac_data %>% rowwise() %>% mutate(New_Var = ifelse(COPY_IND=='Y', Sepal.Length, 'N'))`

Answer (score 0):

1. `COPY_IND` is *always* "Y" in your case, then the code could be simplified to `prac_data$New_Var = prac_data$Sepal.Length`. Even if you want to use `ifelse` statement row-wisely, it is better to follow the instructions in the help document

   > Further note that if(test) yes else no is much more efficient and often much preferable to ifelse(test, yes, no) whenever test is a simple true/false result, i.e., when length(test) == 1.
2. I guess the desired `COPY_IND` should be one column of the data frame/vector rather than a single fixed value. In this case, you code generate the right answer, e.g. keep the first five number:

   ```
   library(dplyr)
   prac_data <- head(iris,10)
   prac_data$COPY_IND=c(rep('Y',5),rep('N',5))
   #COPY_IND=c(rep('Y',5),rep('N',5)) works too
   prac_data <- prac_data %>% mutate(New_Var=ifelse(COPY_IND=='Y', Sepal.Length, 'N'))
   ```

generates the right column.

Comment: Thanks for the note that you provided from the help document. It is really helpful in understanding which is more efficient here. Actually, the 'COPY_IND' can take a value of 'N' too. In that case, I don't want the variable to copy, instead I want the 'New_Var' to be populated with 'N'.